# Groupby, select max from subgroup, compare with a value and make other rows as zero in the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with two columns c1 and c2

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1], 'c2': [0.1, 0.02, 0.5,0.07,0.09,0.8,0.03,0.02]} )
```

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 0.02 |
| 1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.07 |
| 1 | 0.09 |
| -1 | 0.8 |
| -1 | 0.03 |
| -1 | 0.02 |

added another column c3 which is max of c2 grouped on c1

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.02 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.07 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.09 | 0.5 |
| -1 | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| -1 | 0.03 | 0.8 |
| -1 | 0.02 | 0.8 |

```
df['c3'] = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].transform('max')
```

My desired column should first find the max in the sub-group ( c1 has two groups(-1,1) we select category 1 and find max in c2) and once found, we then compare it with condition (>=0.5), if the condition is satisfied then we make the remaining rows of the c1 in the sub-group as zero.

| c1 | c2 | c3 | desired_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.02 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.07 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.09 | 0.5 | 0 |
| -1 | 0.8 | 0.8 | -1 |
| -1 | 0.03 | 0.8 | 0 |
| -1 | 0.02 | 0.8 | 0 |

Comment: Your `c3` column doesn't match your sample data; the values should be `0.3` and `0.4`. Also it's not at all clear why `desired_col` is not `0` for all values since in your table `c3 >= 0.5` for all rows.

Comment: your explanation is hard to understand, and your `desired_col` is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Nick  thanks for pointing that, just updated and added more context!

Comment: @PandaKim edited and added more context

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) :

```
df["desired_col"] = (df["c1"].where(df.groupby("c1")["c2"]
                                    .transform("idxmax").ge(df.index), other=0))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   c1    c2  desired_col
0   1  0.10            1
1   1  0.02            1
2   1  0.50            1
3   1  0.07            0
4   1  0.09            0
5  -1  0.80           -1
6  -1  0.03            0
7  -1  0.02            0
```